# 32k limit retrieving MEDIUMTEXT from mysql using ODBC with oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, odbc, blob, clob

I have a db link on Oracle connecting to a mysql server using ODBC;

In mysql server i have a table with a blob and a mediumtext fields.

If in oracle I execute desc "table'@dblink, oracle shows the blob field as long raw and the mediumtext field as long.

If i execute a query like: select "text_column" from "table"@dblink, it returns only the first 32k of the text. the text is bigger (200k).

Does anyone knows how to solve this limitation between this two servers?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set the `TextSize` parameter in your ODBC connection String? Have you checked if your ODBC driver supports fields larger then 32K? Please elaborate

Comment: mysql say nothing about a text size parameter or limit (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html).

Comment: I´m using ODBC 5.1 Driver